# What is "time-slice multi-threading"?

Tags: operating-systems, concurrency, threads

My goal is to understand the exact differences between SoEMT, SMT and "time-slice multi threading".

Thus far I already found information on [SoEMT](https://sites.google.com/site/paulclaytonplace/andy-glew-s-comparch-wiki/switch-on-event-multithreading-soemt) and [SMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading) and it does not seem to hard to find more on google. However my problem is: Time-slice multithreading. The best I found - apart from a long winded book, was:

– Processor switches between software threads
after a predefined time slice
– Can minimize the effects of long lasting events
– Still, some execution slots are wasted
For Time-slice multithreading I found:

However, this doesn't really go into detail how this things are achieved, for what purpose, its pros, cons and implementations etc.

I would thus be quite happy, if someone knew a good resource, that read up further on that topic. Bonus, if it also compares SoEMT, SMT. As always thanks in advance.

Comment: Fine-grained MT is a type of time-slice multithreading where the time slice is one cycle. *Software* MT generally combines SoEMT (I/O interrupts, blocking system calls, et al.) and coarse-grained time-slice MT (timer interrupt).

Answer (score 2):

Time-slice multithreading is the convectional multithreading where CPU creates an illusion of executing more than once program at a time but the CPU can execute only one of these programs at a time. The OS maintains the illusion of concurrency by rapidly switching between running programs at a fixed interval, called a **time slice**. Time slice multithreading works similar to RoundRobin fashion.

For detailed understanding refer

1. [Definition (Convectional multithreading)](https://arstechnica.com/features/2002/10/hyperthreading/)
2. [Stackoverflow answer](https://superuser.com/questions/740611/what-is-the-difference-between-multithreading-and-hyperthreading)